# How to remove a user from the cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

#### I am using `discord.js` v12.3.1

---

I would like to know how I should go about deleting a user from a cache. For example:

```js
// this would successfully get the user data
client.users.cache.get('<ID Here>');

// delete user from cache

// this time it returns undefined, as the user is no longer stored in the cache
client.users.cache.get('<Same ID>');
```

Is there any way I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting a user, guild, channel, emoji, etc. from the cache is very easy using the [`discord.js collection .delete()` method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=delete).

A quick example of this method in use:

[image: Example]

---

`.delete()` will return `true` if the element was found and removed, or `false` if the element does not exist. It is also identical to [`Map.prototype.delete()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/delete)